# How to make my Discord Bot leave a server Im not in

Tags: javascript, command, bots, discord, discord.js

So i've been trying to make my discord bot leave some servers that Im not in,
I made a command with this `message.guild.leave()` but I could only managed to leave a server that I have access to.

If anyone knows how can I make a command or something to leave one of the servers I would really appreciate it.

Ps: I know the Guild ID of the server I want to leave.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know js library but in .NET this is your problem. I hope u get some idea.

I am pretty sure this is happening because the message is of the type `SocketMessage` and not `SocketGuildMessage`. Cast `message` into `SocketGuildMessage` and you will be able to leave the guild easily. It doesn't matter if you are on the server or not.